# Telephone Call and Electromagnetic Waves

Tags: antenna, communication, electromagnetism, telecommunications, mobile-phones

Can you give me a simple explanation of how do telephone calls work?

I know that when I receive a telephone call, it means that my mobile has just received a certain Electromagnetic field. But in air there are many electromagnetic fields, which correspond to all the telephone calls directed to other numbers. How do my mobile phone understand which is the correct Electromagnetic field? What is the role of the sim card on this?

I think that the receiver antenna of a mobile phone will receive all the electromagnetic fields in the air, and all of them will generate some voltages on it.

Comment: Whatever else, you need to understand basic radio before you can wrap your head around cell phones.

Comment: Don't let how commonplace mobile phones are fool you. Mobile phones and the base stations that they use are EXTREMELY complex. That system is probably the most complex thing by far that most people see and use day-to-day. I don't think a PC even comes close. You will need to do some basic research on your own and come back and ask a more specific question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, a cell phone antenna is bombarded constantly with radio waves from other phones, broadcast radio and TV stations, satellites, wifi routers ... it is a very long list.  Several systems work together to single out the one signal meant for your phone.

The antenna is an efficient receptor only for a narrow range of frequencies.  Next, the receiver circuits use filters to further exclude unwanted signals.  Even if things are narrowed down to only one signal, there could be many phones using that frequency at the same time.  But each phone has a unique digital identifier, part of which is stored on the SIM.  There is a lot of digital signal decoding involved, but each phone is able to separate out only the information that has a matching identifier and is meant for it.  That information is digital data that represents the audio telephone signal.